# How to make three candidate view in softkeyboard?

Tags: android, ime, android-input-method, candidate

I'm developing softkeyboard. My question is how to add three views in candidate view look this image:

[image]

Comment: this information is not sufficient, So explain it. What do you want?

Comment: Please post your answer, how you able to develop it.